# Any advice to sleep 7-8 hours?

Tags: sleep-cycles, sleep-deprivation, waking-up, insomnia, circadian-rythym

I have 24 years, I am in this forum for suggestions, I've never had trouble sleeping, but last year I slept badly because I didn't prepare well for tests and I almost always had to study the last days (and those days I slept bad) and sometimes when I didn't have to study I played games (like LoL) until late at night, now I feel that this has affected me and most nights I only manage to sleep around 6 hours (sometimes more and sometimes less) and I awake even without alarm, I would like to sleep 7 or 8 hours per day.

Anyone who may have been there I could advise?

Comment: @CountIblis <comments deleted> Please do not leave answers in the comments. Instead, it would be appreciated if you leave an actual answer (with references) below.

Comment: Is this even a problem for you? Nowhere in your question do you mention that you feel tired or are unable to concentrate and so on. Why do you think you need more sleep?

Comment: Well,  I thinked that it would be obvious to guess, yeah, I wake up and I feel tired.

Comment: Actually do we need to sleep 8 hrs ?